# How to use ImagePicker to select image and display in Ionic Native

Tags: ionic-framework, uiimagepickercontroller, native

I'm developing an Ionic app, and one task is to select a profile via camera or gallery, and I use Ionic Native ImagePicker to select picture and crop, it can select and crop, but not display in front html page, my code is as below:

```
openImagePickerCrop(){
  this.imagePicker.hasReadPermission().then(
    (result) => {
      if(result == false){
        // no callbacks required as this opens a popup which returns async
        this.imagePicker.requestReadPermission();
      }
      else if(result == true){
        this.imagePicker.getPictures({
          maximumImagesCount: 3
        }).then(
          (results) => {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

              this.crop.crop(results[i], {quality: 100}).then(
                newImage => {
                  this.imgResponse.push('data:image/jpeg;base64,' + newImage);
                  console.log("Image selected - " + newImage);
                },
                error => console.error("Error cropping image", error)
              );

            }
          }, (err) => console.log(err)
        );
      }
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

And this is my html code:

```
<ion-item class="input-item">
          <ion-label position="floating">Photo</ion-label>
          <div class='images' *ngFor="let img of imgResponse">
            <img src="{{img}}" alt="" srcset="" />
          </div>
          <ion-card-content>
            <ion-button color="medium" size="large" (click)="openImagePickerCrop()">
              <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="camera"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
          </ion-card-content>
      </ion-item>
```

Where am I doing wrong, pls help.

**Update:**

To check if it's due to the crop function, I have updated functions as below:

```
openImagePicker(){
this.imagePicker.hasReadPermission().then(
  (result) => {
    if(result == false){
      // no callbacks required as this opens a popup which returns async
      this.imagePicker.requestReadPermission();
    }
    else if(result == true){
      this.imagePicker.getPictures({
        maximumImagesCount: 1
      }).then(
        (results) => {

          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            this.imgResponse.push('data:image/jpeg;base64,' + results[i]);
            console.log("Image selected - " + results[i]);
          }
        }, (err) => console.log(err)
      );
    }
  }, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

But still not working, and the console doesn't capture anything.

Comment: Can you tell me what was the output of `console.log("Image selected")` ?

Comment: Actually I don't see the console output, no error either, the only output is as below: 2019-06-02 17:05:24.523626+0800 Handly[64364:5167536] corrected orientation: 0
2019-06-02 17:05:29.291482+0800 Handly[64364:5166193] GMImagePicker: User finished picking assets. Number of selected items is: 1
2019-06-02 17:06:01.086576+0800 Handly[64364:5168711] [MC] Invalidating cache
2019-06-02 17:06:03.142675+0800 Handly[64364:5168711] [MC] Invalidating cache

Comment: So, i think something going wrong in croping image.

Comment: To isolate the issue, I have removed the crop part, and my new function is as my updated part, but still no console output, no error and no image display :(